# iPhone simulator slow startup on iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

For some reason the iPhone simulator takes several seconds (~12-13s) to start my app when I run it in iOS 6.0 or 6.1 mode (that's before the app's default screen appears, so it doesn't seem to be caused by the app's code). I think that's actually slower than when I start the app on the device. If I switch to 5.0 or 5.1 it takes just 2-3 seconds.

Has anyone else noticed this? Any solutions? (I've cleared the whole `~/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` directory, but it didn't help.)

Comment: I've noticed that as well. I just assumed it was normal…

Comment: Same happened to me when trying to use NSLayoutConstraints to place and size 50 or so views dynamically from viewDidLoad. Wouldn't happen with ios5 as NSLayoutConstarints aren't supported.

Comment: @Steve: I don't think it's that, I don't use autolayout at all in that app. And the delay happens while the simulator's screen is still black, or even before its window appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can select iOS Simulator from top menu. After it you can Reset Contents and Settings (third from top). it will reset you simulator. Remove all application from your simulator. Please try after it.